# How to implement a binary search method to find matching string in two different text files

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, string-matching

So i have two different text files. The first text file contains:

```
Apple
Banana
Berry
Lemon
Orange
```

The second one contains:

```
Banana
Juice
Kiwi
Strawberry
Water
```

The matching string I want outputted is "banana". I know how to implement this using hashsets, arraylists, and etc. But i want to use a binary search method. But I keep getting stuck because instead of dealing with integers, I am dealing with strings. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean BinarySearch() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String compare;

        java.io.File firstlist= new java.io.File("firstlist.txt");
        Scanner scanner1= new Scanner(firstlist);

        java.io.File secondlist= new java.io.File("secondlist.txt");
        Scanner scanner2= new Scanner(secondlist);

        ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner2.hasNextLine()){
            names.add(scanner2.nextLine());
        }

        int low =0;
        int high = list.size() -1;

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            compare=scanner1.nextLine();
            scanner2= new Scanner(list);

            while (high>=low){
                int middle = (low+high)/2;
                if (list.get(middle) == list.get(0)){
                    return 1;
                }
                if (list.get(middle) < list.get(0))
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Main rule of Binary Search is The List must be sorted

Comment: @AshrafulIslam you're right, sorry. I will sort out the list.

Comment: Where do you initialize variables names, firstlist, secondlist? It is not obvious from the code.

Comment: @VasiliyVlasov i just corrected my code, sorry about that

Comment: You're missing `if (list.get(middle) > list.get(0)) {high = middle - 1;}`

Comment: i can see a lot of problems in your code 1- `scanner2 = new Scanner(list);` scanner can't accept a List 2- your method return boolean so you cant return `return 1;` 3- Strings should be compared by .equals not by == so instead of `if (list.get(middle) == list.get(0)) {` you have to use `if (list.get(middle).equals(list.get(0))) {` the last one you cant compare String with operators like < or > like you do here `if (list.get(middle) < list.get(0)) {`

Comment: Use Comparator to compare strings and decide on high and low on the result of the comparison..

Comment: @YCF_L so for the very last thing you said where i can't compare strings with operators, what would I do?

Comment: i don't know why you are using < maybe you mean not equal `(!list.get(middle).equals(list.get(0)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two `strings` with operators.

`String a, b;`

`a == b` checks if a and b are the **SAME OBJECT**. This will always be false.

Instead, use `String.equals((String) a)` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two main ideas of binary search:

- sorted list
- comparision function

As I understand, your strings in files are sorted using alphabetic order. `String.compareTo` is what you need for binary search, when you make desision about left or right part:

```
while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
    int middleIndex = (rightIndex + leftIndex) / 2;
    String middle = strings[middleIndex];
    if (target.compareTo(middle) < 0) {
        rightIndex = middleIndex;
    } else {
        leftIndex = middle;
    }
}
```